# Log Spring Security Principal in Grails

Tags: grails, log4j, spring-security

How can I log the User Principal in my Log4J Log with Grails?

I want to see the name of the current login when an exception occurs, ie logging the current principal on each action would not work. I need the username stored so when an exception occurs the User Name can be in the Log Pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you should go with log4j's Nested Diagnostic Contexts (NDC). See the respective chapter in http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html.

The idea is to create a grails filter hat manages NDC data (push/pop) upon every request and use %x in your logger's pattern, see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html.

By doing so, you have separated the burden of logging from the controller/service login.

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService), you could use `grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService` utility class for this purpose.

```
class SomeController {    
     def springSecurityService    
     def someAction = { 
         def principal = springSecurityService.principal 
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I need the username stored so when an exception occurs the User Name can be in the Log Pattern.